# C# - Change location on radiobutton1, 2, 3 and 4

Tags: c#, class, random

How can i make random location on radioButton1, radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4?

So it looks like this:

```
RADIO1 text = hello
RADIO2 text = yo
RADIO3 text = omg
RADIO4 text = test
```

And when i press button1, it will be random like:

```
RADIO2 text = yo
RADIO1 text = hello
RADIO4 text = test
RADIO3 text = omg
```

And make them change pleace on every button click, BUT without being able to overwrite eachoter, so radio1 and radio2 cannot be same location.

I have tried with the Random() Class like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"radioButton1","radioButton2","radioButton3","radioButton4"};
public void ShuffleText(){
var rand = new Random();
var shuffledText = list.OrderBy(x=>rand.Next(list.Count)).ToList();
var radioButtons = new[]{radioButton1,radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4};
for(int i = 0; i < radioButtons.Length;i++)
radioButtons[i].Text = shuffledText[i];
```

That inside a button1.click event. But doesn't work..
The Radiobutton names; radioButton1, radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4.

But i'm not sure how to do it.. Can someones please help me out? :-)

Comment: You can't overwrite radio buttons. They can overlap, but you can always move them. Each `RadioButton` has a `Location` property. Just play with it. Or are you asking about the actual values that you need to generate?

Comment: @AndreiV - Hehe, the the actual would be nice to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the `Location`, you can just change their `Text`. Save all the `Text` in some `List<string>` and reassign the Texts randomly on every button click:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>{"hello","yo","omg","test"};
public void ShuffleText(){
  var rand = new Random();
  var shuffledText = list.OrderBy(x=>rand.Next(list.Count)).ToList();
  var radioButtons = new[]{radioButton1,radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4};
  for(int i = 0; i < radioButtons.Length;i++)
    radioButtons[i].Text = shuffledText[i];
}
```

It's not clear on your `UI` technology, if it's `winforms` just keep the code above, if it's `WPF`, just use the property `Content` instead of `Text`.

### UPDATE

In fact you can define your own structure for each choice with more properties including some property like `IsAnswer`. However to make it simple as what you require (shuffle the location), you can use the following code instead:

```
public void ShuffleLocation(){
  var rand = new Random();
  var radioButtons = new[]{radioButton1,radioButton2, radioButton3, radioButton4};
  var shuffledLocations = radioButtons.Select(r=>r.Location)
                                      .OrderBy(x=>rand.Next(radioButtons.Length));
  int i = 0;
  foreach(var loc in shuffledLocations)
     radioButtons[i++].Location = loc;
}
```

The updated code works only if you use `winforms`, for `wpf`, you have to put all the radiobuttons on a `Canvas` and use the static methods `SetLeft` and `SetTop` of the `Canvas` class.

Comment: I was preparing a `Fisher-Yates Shuffle` answer but this is far more simple and straightforward. No need to over-complicate things...

Comment: But then it will mess up the setup. Because it is for a quiz application i am making. And i have a code on textchange, if (question.text = "question here") then answertextbox = "answer1" and continues with 4 different answer choises.

Comment: Edit: Because this is for a quiz application, the text can't be changed like that. This was a tricky one for me.. Can't really find out the correct solution

List<string> list = new List<string>{"hello","yo","omg","test"};
Should be like:
List<string> list = new List<string>{"radioButton1","radioButton2","radioButton3","radioButton4"};
Is it possible to do it like that one way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StackPanel and add RadioButton in a random order.

XAML :

```
<StackPanel x:Name="sp">
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb1" Content="hello"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb2" Content="yo"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb3" Content="omg"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb4" Content="test"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In code behind (in Window_loaded in my example) :

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // empty the stackPanel
    sp.Children.Clear();

    // create a list of RadioButtons
    List<UIElement> listElement = new List<UIElement>();
    listElement.Add(rb1);
    listElement.Add(rb2);
    listElement.Add(rb3);
    listElement.Add(rb4);

    // Randomize the list and fill the stackpanel with linq
    listElement.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList()         // randomize list
               .ForEach(element => sp.Children.Add(element)); // add each radiobutton
}
```

**Edit**. Better code behind, with all element you want (radiobutton, button, usercontrol ...):

```
private void Randomize()
{
    List<UIElement> listElement = new List<UIElement>();

    while (sp.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        listElement.Add(sp.Children[0]);
        sp.Children.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    listElement.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList()
               .ForEach(element => sp.Children.Add(element));
}

// randomize at startup
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Randomize();
}

// randomize as action
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Randomize();
}
```

Comment: Because this is for a quiz application, the text can't be changed like that. This was a tricky one for me.. Can't really find out the correct solution List<string> list = new List<string>{"hello","yo","omg","test"}; Should be like: List<string> list = new List<string>{"radioButton1","radioButton2","radioButton3","radioButton4"}; Is it possible to do it like that one way?

Comment: that's not randomize strings, it's randomize Buttons in the UI. Each radio button has a string and that doesn't change. May be I haven't understood your need...